# Json4s date to unixtimestamp

Tags: json, scala, json4s

How to create wrapper for Json4s? Default json4s formater date converted all to SimpleDateFormat. I want convert all date field to unixtime format.

Comment: what do you mean "unixtime" format? a unix timestamp? ie: a signed 32bit integer?

Comment: yes. long interpretation of date. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time such as new Date().getTime()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to implement your own `Formats`. Here is a simplified example, which is based on the [SerializationExamples](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/tests/src/test/scala/org/json4s/native/SerializationExamples.scala).

**EDIT**: updated example

```
import java.util.Date
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

object Main extends App {

  implicit val formats = new DefaultFormats {
    override val dateFormat: DateFormat = new DateFormat {
      override def parse(s: String): Option[Date] = Some(new Date(s.toLong * 1000))
      override def format(d: Date): String = (d.getTime/1000).toString
    }
  }

  case class Lotto(id: Long, drawDate: Date)

  val lotto = Lotto(3L, new Date())

  val ser: String = Serialization.write(lotto)
  println(ser) // prints value 'drawDate' as unix time
  println(Serialization.read[Lotto](ser)) // prints deserialized Lotto instance
}
```

Comment: Serius? I can do it in DTO level with convert all dates to LONG "new Date().getTime"

Comment: Then why don't you do it? What's the point of your question then, when not changing the serialization format of dates?

Answer (score -1):

If your project allow it... instead of writing any new piece of code, why no to use moment.js.  It certainly give you the option to have unix output there.

[unix function in moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/)

Comment: I write not only JS. And string as dates sucks.

Comment: momentjs is just a way to manipulate the date, you can always have it back for internal storing in date datatype.  Down voter, nice to know the reason so I can try to improve the answer... which besides was more of a comment... but I didn't have the privileges before :) ... or to have a better non-opinion based question :)